# How to import code from adjacent file in Golang

Tags: go

I have the canonical problem when learning a new programming language. I have this:

```
$GOPATH/
   src/
     huru/
       foo/
          side.go
       hello.go
```

In hello.go I have:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


func main(){
   Foo()
}
```

And in foo/side.go, I have:

```
package main

func Foo() {

}
```

I run:

```
go install huru
```

and I get:

```
# huru
src/huru/hello.go:22:2: undefined: Foo
```

the compiler doesn't like the `Foo()` call in `hello.go`, how do I import it properly? Should I be using `package main` for both files?  Why wouldn't the package be called `huru`, I assume I should call the package `huru`..instead of `main`?

Comment: you didn't write your `main()` all functions calls should be from within functions.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include that in hello.go in my code example, but that's not the problem, let me add it tho

Comment: you are trying to call a function from global space, you should call it either from `main()` or from inside some other function.

Comment: @nilsocket ah yes, Foo() has to be called from within a func as you say, I put it in main and it works

Comment: I updated the question to be more useful ... I am now trying to source `"$GOPATH/src/huru/foo/side.go"` from `"$GOPATH/src/huru/hello.go"` and it's not working, I get the error shown.

Comment: when you are placing a file in a directory, it is considered as new package, `foo/side.go`. you need to import it as `huru/foo` and change `package foo` in `side.go` and call in `main()` as `foo.Foo()`,It is not a good practice to name in go.consider learning basics from [here](https://tour.golang.org).

Comment: only one package can be named main.

Comment: for more information about go, refer [go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki)

Comment: I think this answers the question: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2lq3it/is_there_a_way_to_arrange_go_code_into_multiple/

Comment: change package name in `side.go`, even though it solves your problem, consider taking a go tour and reading from go wiki.

Comment: the go wiki and docs don't seem to answer this fundamental question, the reddit article did though. Instead of the docs, youtube videos are probably better, idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use `main` as the package name of `huru/foo/side.go`, because it's already used in the `huru/hello.go` where the path is different than where `side.go` located.

So change the package name on the `huru/foo/side.go` file. [Better to use folder name as the package name](https://blog.golang.org/package-names).

```
package foo

func Foo() {

}
```

Then on the `huru/hello.go`, import the `huru/foo` package so you'll be able to consume the `Foo()` function that defined on the file inside.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "huru/foo" // <------ here
)

func main(){
   foo.Foo()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [Go Documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution), a program is defined by a single unimported `main` package.  You can't have multiple `main` packages in a program, so if you want to make a library, e.g. your `foo` dir, you need to define a different package name.

Also included in the documentation is [a description](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) for how imports are handled.  To be fair, it's a bit cryptic and they don't explicitly mention `$GOPATH`, but imports are taken relative to it.  You can't import a package relative to a specific file, however.

Your code will compile fine if you do something like this:

hello.go:

```
package main

import . "huru/foo"

func main() {
        Foo()
}
```

foo/side.go:

```
package foo

import "fmt"

func Foo() {
        fmt.Println("Hello from side.go");
}
```

Comment: upvoted, yeah sorry - I changed the question a tiny bit sorry, now I am trying to import "foo/side.go" from "hello.go".

Comment: No worries, let me just update my answer... FYI go doesn't have relative imports so you have to import it as `huru/foo` and change the package name.